# Polymer 3 Data Binding not updating on property set

Tags: polymer-3.x

I have an Polymer 3 module (simplified/wrong below to explain only);

```
import {html,PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
class myInput extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html `
            <input id="inputBox" value='{{bar::input}}'/><br/>
            <a>You have typed [[bar]]!</a>
        `;
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            bar: {
            observer: '_dataChanged',
        },
    }

    _dataChanged () {
        this.bar = "BAR HAS CHANGED!!"
    }
}
```

`[[bar]]` is successfully updated & displayed on page.

`{{bar::input}}` successfully fires `_dataChanged`.

But `[[bar]]` does not update & display `"BAR HAS CHANGED!!"` on page when `_dataChanged()` is triggered.

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have youn tried replacing {{bar::input}} with {{bar}} ?

Comment: @Cy Walker ,  How you call `_clickMe()` function. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the polymer button element. Then you can bind the value to the `bar` property easy. Here the example:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zjl38r?file=index.js)

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from '@polymer/polymer';
import '@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js'

class MyElement extends PolymerElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            bar: {
            observer: '_dataChanged',
        }
    }}

  static get template() {
    return html`
            <input id="inputBox" value='{{bar::input}}'/><br/>
            <paper-button on-tap="_clickMe">You have typed [[bar]]!</paper-button>
        `;
  }

    _dataChanged(d){console.log(d)}
    _clickMe () {
        this.bar = "CLICKED!!"
    }

}
customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

Comment: Thanks HakanC - this got me looking closer at what I was doing & the errors. It was actually due to another import (not in example provided) causing the issue, not a polymer issue. Cheers.